# Angular ng-max issue with bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created the following plunker to show my problem:

http://embed.plnkr.co/8b4GTlRwYGKjmbcjgNvT/preview

Basically, when the value bound to an input exceeds the ng-max value, the binding is lost, which makes sense in a way but when I clear the input / model. The value is not cleared, any thoughts?

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one your clearValues function destroys everything inside of `$scope.item` instead of only resetting the value of `$scope.item.currentValue`

Try something more like...

```
$scope.clearValues = function() {
    $scope.item.currentValue = 0;
};
```

Comment: The way you were doing it before left the model to remain the same, despite the fact that it dissapeared after exceeding 10. It only vanished from the view because the input box wouldn't allow it, but the data was still there.

Comment: Thanks. Initially I wasnt that keen on having to re-initialise all properties of my model as the model is populated from the server. But this led me to rethink things and reset my model from the server rather than on the client.